# Why does a click on my link not fire?

Tags: html, css

What I'm expecting is that clicking the h3 will allow the anchor inside of it to work but for some reason it's not.
I have a Fiddle demonstrating the issue is here: https://jsfiddle.net/05fekvgy/

CSS

```
.sitting-timeline-bar-error {
  background-color: #ec1439;
}
.sitting-timeline-item-error {
  background-color: #ec1439;
}
.sitting-timeline-header-error {
  color: #ec1439;
}
/* Action Class for timeline */
.sitting-timeline-bar-action {
  background-color: #0c8ed9;
}
.sitting-timeline-item-action {
  background-color: #0c8ed9;
}
.sitting-timeline-header-action {
  color: #0c8ed9;
}
/* Positive Class for timeline */
.sitting-timeline-bar-positive {
  background: #42bc8d;
}
.sitting-timeline-item-positive {
  background: #42bc8d;
}
.sitting-timeline-header {
  color: #42bc8d;
}
.timeline-wrapper p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #b7b7b7;
}
.timeline-wrapper h3 {
  color: #efefef;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.timeline-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.sitting-timeline-section {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: -2000;
}
.sitting-timeline-section-description {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: -2000;
  padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.sitting-timeline-bar {
  background-color: #efefef;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: -1px;
  z-index: -1000;
}
.sitting-timeline-section-start,
.sitting-timeline-section-end {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: -2000;
}
.sitting-timeline-section-start .sitting-timeline-bar {
  left: 50%;
}
.sitting-timeline-section-end .sitting-timeline-bar {
  width: 50%;
}
.sitting-timeline-item {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #efefef;
  /*@brand-unselected*/
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="timeline-wrapper">
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section-start timeline-section">
            <div class="sitting-timeline-bar"></div>
            <div class="sitting-timeline-item icon-test-title-wizard"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section timeline-section">
            <div class="sitting-timeline-bar"></div>
            <div class="sitting-timeline-item icon-date-time-wizard"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section timeline-section">
            <div class="sitting-timeline-bar"></div>
            <div class="sitting-timeline-item icon-students-wizard"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section timeline-section">
            <div class="sitting-timeline-bar"></div>
            <div class="sitting-timeline-item icon-invigilation-wizard-"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section-end timeline-section">
            <div class="sitting-timeline-bar"></div>
            <div class="sitting-timeline-item icon-summary-wizard"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-wrapper">
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section-description">
            <h3><a href="http://www.google.com">Add Title &amp; Test</a>
            </h3>
            <p class="font-size-small">Give your sitting a Title (ID) & choose the test.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section-description">
            <h3><a href="#">Date &amp; Time</a>
            </h3>
            <p class="font-size-small">Choose the date and time that you would like your sitting.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section-description">
            <h3>Add Students</h3>
            <p class="font-size-small">Add individuals or anonymous students to your Sitting.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section-description">
            <h3>Invigilation mode</h3>
            <p class="font-size-small">Choose the method of which you would like to invigilate this sitting.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sitting-timeline-section-description">
            <h3>Summary</h3>
            <p class="font-size-small">Check if your details are correct then create your sitting.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about you reduce your testcase to the [minimum](https://jsfiddle.net/05fekvgy/9/) required HTML / CSS to reproduce the issue and go from there? That way you'll be able to see much easier the forrest for the trees. Basic debugging skills.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> .sitting-timeline-section {
>   z-index: -2000;
> }
> ```

You've put it behind the `<body>`, so when you try to click it, you click the body element instead.

Avoid negative z-indexes.

Answer (score 3):

It is caused by negative `z-index`. So logically you are trying to decrease the stacking order of the element behind other elements and the click is applied on them, not on anchor tags.

```
.sitting-timeline-section-description {
  z-index: -2000; /* Remove or increase to +ve value */
}
```

*Note: There are negative z-index values on multiple classes. I just pointed out one occurrence of the code, please try to avoid negative z-index*

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/05fekvgy/2/)